# Giving Row number to the word automatin table

Tags: c#

I want to give line number to the word automation table via bookmarks. How can we do it? My codes are below.

[image]

These are my codes.

```
using System;

using System.Data;

using System.Data.OleDb;

using System.Reflection;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using System.Windows.Forms;

using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;





namespace Deneme

{

    public partial class Form3 : Form

    {

        public Form3()

        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private DataTable GetDataSource()

        {

            var dt = new DataTable();

            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=gezievrak2541.mdb; Mode = ReadWrite"))

            {

                conn.Open();

                using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT tcno, sinifi FROM gezilistemiz25  where sinifi IS NOT NULL GROUP BY tcno, sinifi order BY  Left(sinifi,1) desc,Left(sinifi,13) asc,Left(sinifi,12) asc", conn))



                {

                    adapter.Fill(dt);

                }

                return dt;

            }

        }



        private void Sabitbilgi()

        {

            DataTable dt = GetDataSource();



            object oMissing = Missing.Value;

            Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();

            oWord.Visible = true;

            object oTemplatePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Deneme.docx";

            Word.Document oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

            object Index = "sinifi";

            Word.Table tbl = oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref Index).Range.Tables[1];





            int i = 1; foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows) r["tcno"] = i++; // satir numarasi verir

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)

            {

                Word.Row newRow = tbl.Rows.Add(ref oMissing);

                for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Columns.Count; j++)

                {

                    newRow.Cells[j].Range.Text = dr[j - 1].ToString();

                }

            }

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tbl);

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWordDoc);

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWord);

        }



        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            Sabitbilgi();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the numbers and totals of male and female students according to the classes, you need to modify your code to include grouping and counting.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace Deneme
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private DataTable GetDataSource()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=gezievrak2541.mdb; Mode = ReadWrite"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT tcno, sinifi, cinsiyet FROM gezilistemiz25 WHERE sinifi IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Left(sinifi,1) DESC, Left(sinifi,13) ASC, Left(sinifi,12) ASC", conn))
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
                return dt;
            }
        }

        private void Sabitbilgi()
        {
            DataTable dt = GetDataSource();

            object oMissing = Missing.Value;
            Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
            oWord.Visible = true;
            object oTemplatePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Deneme.docx";
            Word.Document oWordDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            object index = "sinifi";
            Word.Table tbl = oWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref index).Range.Tables[1];

            int maleCount = 0;
            int femaleCount = 0;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Word.Row newRow = tbl.Rows.Add(ref oMissing);
                for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    newRow.Cells[j].Range.Text = dr[j - 1].ToString();
                }

                string gender = dr["cinsiyet"].ToString().ToLower();
                if (gender == "male")
                    maleCount++;
                else if (gender == "female")
                    femaleCount++;
            }

            Word.Row totalsRow = tbl.Rows.Add(ref oMissing);
            totalsRow.Cells[1].Range.Text = "Male Total:";
            totalsRow.Cells[2].Range.Text = maleCount.ToString();

            totalsRow = tbl.Rows.Add(ref oMissing);
            totalsRow.Cells[1].Range.Text = "Female Total:";
            totalsRow.Cells[2].Range.Text = femaleCount.ToString();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tbl);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWordDoc);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWord);
        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sabitbilgi();
        }
    }
}
```